# What is this Perl string encoded in?

Tags: perl, encoding

I'm using use Mail::IMAPClient to retrieve mail headers from an imap server. It works great. But when the header contains any character other that [a-z|A-Z|0-9] I'm served with strings that look like this :

- Subject : Un message en =?UTF-8?B?ZnJhbsOnYWlzIMOgIGxhIGNvbg==?= (original string : "Un message en français à la con")
- Body :
  =C3=A9aeio=C3=B9=C3=A8=C3=A8 (original string : éaeioùèè)

  1. What is this strange format ? Is that the famous "perl string
     internal" format ?
  2. what is the safest way of handling human idioms
     coming from IMAP servers ?

Comment: If you plan to do anything at all with email, you should acquire at least a basic familiarity with MIME.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The body encoding is Quoted-Printable; the header (subject) encoding is MIME "encoded-word" encoding ("B" type for base64). The best way to deal with both of them is to pass the email into a module that's capable of dealing with MIME, such as [Email::MIME](https://metacpan.org/module/Email::MIME) or the older and buggier [MIME::Lite](https://metacpan.org/module/MIME::Lite).

For example:

```
# $message was retrieved from IMAP
my $mime = Email::MIME->new($message);
my $subject = $mime->header('Subject'); # automatically decoded
my $body = $mime->body_str; # also automatically decoded
```

However if you need to deal with them outside of the context of an entire message, there are also modules like [Encode::MIME::Header](https://metacpan.org/module/Encode::MIME::Header) and [MIME::QuotedPrint](https://metacpan.org/module/MIME::QuotedPrint).

Answer (score 7):

It is [quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) coded. It is a standard encoding used in email. It has nothing to do with Perl's internal string format.